# Issues centring the a div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to centre a div but for some reason the div doesn't get centred. The code is avaialble [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/redeagle-website-0j91ie?file=/index.html).

In the image below you can see which is the issue.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use same ID for elements, use classes instead.

Anyways the problem is that your flex items are not the same size.

set them to same width:

```
width: calc(100% / 3);
```

Comment: What's the different between `id` and `class`?

Comment: @Tommodev id's are unique, means only allowed once. Classes you can use on multiple elements.

Answer (score 1):

It is aligned to the center, its just that some of the "#featuresBoxes" divs are bigger than the other. The easy fix is to change the #featuresBoxes css as following:

```
#featuresBoxes {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  color: white;
  padding: 40px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
}
```